# Passing datatable as value in keyvaluepair object truncates string

Tags: c#, sql

When passing a datatable as an object in a keyvaluepair how do you prevent a string from being restricted to 4000 characters in the db? In the following code if a string is >4000 chars it is not written to the db, but a debug identifies the column in the datatable does have the >4000 chars string:

```
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// Handle the parameters 
if (args != null)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> arg in args)
    {
        SqlParameter param;
        param = new SqlParameter();                          
        param.ParameterName = "@" + arg.Key;
        param.Value = arg.Value; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
}

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

// Fill the DataTable.                        
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: What is the column type in the database?

Comment: col type in db is nvarchar(max)

Comment: How is the datatable parameter translated to the Select command?

Comment: ie. if you use sql server profile what is passed as the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to explicitly set the type of you parametr to SqlDbType.NVarChar

```
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
```

Quoting from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx):

> NVarChar: String. A variable-length stream of Unicode characters
>   ranging between 1 and 4,000 characters. Implicit conversion fails if
>   the string is greater than 4,000 characters. **Explicitly set the object
>   when working with strings longer than 4,000 characters**. Use NVarChar
>   when the database column is nvarchar(max).

Comment: I don't know how to do this. I have also seen the text you have found on MSDN

Comment: The parameter is a table, not a string

Comment: you have an "object" in your dictionary, that you use as parameter value: what is the actual type of this object? ("table" is not a type, as far as I know)

Comment: Gian  var dtToDbJsonObject = new DataTable();